# Unable to read local json file on live Vercel site using getServerSideProps?

Tags: vercel, http-status-code-500, next-auth

Im having issues deploying a project on Vercel. On my local machine the app is working as expected. Yet on the live site I'm running into a 500 internal error message. The project uses MongoDB and Next-Auth. In the .env.local file I created a env variable for NEXTAUTH_URL = localhost/3000. In Vercel, I created a NEXTAUTH_URL = "project-site" env variable for production. At the moment there isn't any MongoDB env variable set up. The error message in the function logs reads out

```
[GET] /_next/data/A8gtiRNZmw7m2Db85BoGe/suggestions.json
15:40:24:81
2022-05-26T19:40:26.691Z    e41995a4-dac5-4f4e-aa1c-fbbcd2787d91    ERROR   [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/public/data/data.json'] {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/var/task/public/data/data.json',
  page: '/suggestions'
}
RequestId: e41995a4-dac5-4f4e-aa1c-fbbcd2787d91 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

Any tips are greatly appreciated.